# ng-bootstrap not working in angular 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap, angular4-forms

I am new with angular 4, I am trying to configure bootstrap.
I installed ng-bootstrap:

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

I did all like on the page, but I don't see the bootstrap on my page.
Here is my code:

src/app/app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   FormsModule,  // add  this
   NgbModule.forRoot()
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

src/app/app.component.html

```
<div class="container">

<h1 class="text-primary">{{title}} </h1>

<h2 class="text-primary">My Heroes</h2>
<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
    [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
    (click)="onSelect(hero)">
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
   </li>
</ul>

<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
 <strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this important alert 
   message.
</div>

<div *ngIf="selectedHero">
  <h2>{{selectedHero.name}} details!</h2>
<div><label>id: </label>{{selectedHero.id}}</div>
<div>
  <label>name: </label>
  <input [(ngModel)]="selectedHero.name" placeholder="name"/>
</div>
```

I tried also some code in the index.html, but it does not work,

for this line I am expecting to see some color:

```
<h1 class="text-primary">{{title}} </h1>
```

I don't find any reference of bootstrap when I check the header of the html.
Any help, please?
Thanks

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In the page you mentioned, ng-bootstrap mentions bootstrap CSS as a dependency. So that's loaded separately.

If you are using Angular CLI to create your application, you can [follow this official guide](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-include-bootstrap) to add it,

#### Update:

As mentioned in the comment, adding the CSS to `styles` in `.angular-cli.json` (or any other changes to this file) will require you to restart your `ng serve` or `ng build --watch` if you have either already running.

#### Update 2 (Current Recommended Approach):

For Angular 6 and higher you can use this solution.

Go to `styles.css` and add this line

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

See also how this works under the hood:

https://blog.angularindepth.com/this-is-how-angular-cli-webpack-delivers-your-css-styles-to-the-client-d4adf15c4975

Comment: thanks a lot, I needed to restart the ng serve, it is working nice! thanks

Comment: thanks, for me the following works: 
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

Comment: For Angular 6 and higher you can use this solution.

Go to styles.css and add this line

@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";   its work cool

Comment: Yes, that's what Update 2 from September 2018 recommended. I made it more clear this is the recommended approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any ng-bootstrap component in your code! I think you are looking for bootstrap css, which is also a prerequisite for ng-bootstrap.

Add these lines in `index.html` between the `<head></head>` tag:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```