# ngbootstrap not working Angular

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to use ngbootstrap on angular (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples)

I tried the first example:

app.component.html

```
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" activeIds="ngb-panel-0">
  <ngb-panel title="Simple">
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia
      aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor,
      sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
      craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings
      occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus
      labore sustainable VHS.
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
  <ngb-panel>
    <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
      <span>&#9733; <b>Fancy</b> title &#9733;</span>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia
      aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor,
      sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
      craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings
      occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus
      labore sustainable VHS.
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
  <ngb-panel title="Disabled" [disabled]="true">
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia
      aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor,
      sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
      craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings
      occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus
      labore sustainable VHS.
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```

angular.json

```
"styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I checked that [ng-bootstrap not working in angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991218/ng-bootstrap-not-working-in-angular-4) but still not working after compiling...

What am I doing wrong ?

Edit: here is a screenshot:

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxb3u.png)

Comment: take account your bootstrap.css was bootstrap.css.4.0.0

Comment: @Eliseo bootstrap.css is v3.3.7

Comment: Then you must replace your bootstrap.css by the bootstrap.css from the version 4.0.0 or higger, see https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

Comment: Woaw you were right, it was a bootstrap.css problem however I followed the steps indicated on "getting started", they should update it. I downloaded the latest version of bootstrap and replaced it in node_modules bootstrap/dist/css manually and it's working now. Thank's a lot